# React Js Error Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am working on a login logout components and everything is working fine but sometimes this error pops up **Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method** i have searched on internet and tried many solutions but nothing is working for me

## here is my login component

```
class Login extends Component {

_isMounted = false;

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    let token = localStorage.getItem("Token")
    let isloggedIn = true
    if (token == null) {
        isloggedIn = false
    }
    let authToken = undefined
    this.state = {
        userName: undefined,
        userPassword: undefined,
        isToken: false,
        isloggedIn,
        authToken
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    this._isMounted = true;
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
}




SetUserName = (event) => {
    this.setState({ userName: event.target.value })

}

SetUserPassword = (event) => {
    this.setState({ userPassword: event.target.value })
}

SubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this._isMounted = true;

    console.log("button clicked")

    var reqData = {
        "username": this.state.userName,
        "password": this.state.userPassword,
        "grant_type": "password"
    };

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://192.168.100.35/token',
        withCredentials: true,
        crossdomain: true,
        data: $.param(reqData),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",

        }
    }).then(response => {
        if (this._isMounted) {
            console.log(response.data)
            this.setState({ isToken: true })
            this.setState({ isloggedIn: true })
            this.setState({ authToken: response.data.access_token })
            localStorage.setItem("Token", this.state.authToken)

        }





    })
}

render() {

    if (this.state.isloggedIn) {
        return <Redirect to="/getStudentsByClass" />
    }

    return (
        <div className="Login">
            <div className="c-card u-mb-xsmall">
                <header className="c-card__header u-pt-large">
                    <a>

                    </a>
                    <h1 className="u-h3 u-text-center u-mb-zero">Welcome Back! Please Login.</h1>

                </header>
                <form className="c-card__body">
                    <div className="c-field u-mb-small">
                        <label className="c-field__label">
                            Log in with your e-mail address
                        </label>
                        <input className="c-input" value={this.state.userName} onChange={this.SetUserName} type="text" placeholder="clark@dashboard.com"></input>

                    </div>
                    <div className="c-field u-mb-small">
                        <label className="c-field__label">
                            Password
                        </label>
                        <input className="c-input" value={this.state.userPassword} onChange={this.SetUserPassword} type="password" placeholder="Letters, Numbers"></input>

                    </div>
                    <button className="c-btn c-btn--info c-btn--fullwidth"
                        onClick={this.SubmitHandler}>
                        Sign in to Dashboard
                    </button>
                    <span className="c-divider c-divider--small has-text u-mv-medium">
                        Login Via Social Networks

                    </span>
                    <div className="o-line">
                        <a className="c-icon u-bg-twitter">
                            <i className="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a className="c-icon u-bg-facebook">
                            <i className="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a className="c-icon u-bg-pinterest">
                            <i className="fa fa-pinterest"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a className="c-icon u-bg-dribbble">
                            <i className="fa fa-dribbble"></i>
                        </a>

                    </div>

                </form>

            </div>
            <div className="o-line">
                <a className="u-text-mute u-text-small">
                    Don’t have an account yet? Get Started

                </a>
                <a className="u-text-mute u-text-small">
                    Forgot Password?

                </a>

            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
}
```

## here is my logout component

```
class Logout extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    localStorage.removeItem("Token")
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h2>You Have Been Logged Out</h2>
            <Link to="/">Login</Link>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

## here is my GetStudentsByClass Component

```
class  GetStudentsByClass extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    let token = localStorage.getItem("Token")
    let isloggedIn = true
    if(token == null){
        isloggedIn = false
    }
    this.state = {
        isloggedIn
    }
}



render(){
    if(this.state.isloggedIn === false){
        return <Redirect to="/"/>
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1> Get Student By Class</h1>
            <Link to="/Logout">Logout</Link>

        </div>

    )

}
```

}

Comment: Do you want the form to be submitted when you press the button ? If not, just remove the `<form>` element or prevent it from being submitted.

Comment: yes i want to submit the form

Comment: i have removed the form but problem is still there @tit

Comment: Never mind that, I see that you have a `e.preventDefault()` call in the `SubmitHandler ` function which is called when the button is pressed.

Comment: i have added this because i dont know for some reason when i press my button my page refreshes it self even if there is no code in submithandler

Comment: Yes, that is what happens (page refreshes) when there is only one button in a form and you press it (is considered a `submit` button), I thought that was the problem but it must be something else.

Comment: so how i can solve it

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this issue either by aborting the request when your component unmounts or preventing this.setState() on an unmounted component.

You can call SubmitHandler() method inside ComponentDidMount() and remove

```
this._isMounted = true;
```

inside SubmitHandler(e) method.
Ex.

```
componentDidMount(){
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.onClickSubmitHandler();
}

onClickSubmitHandler() {
 SubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("button clicked")

    var reqData = {
        "username": this.state.userName,
        "password": this.state.userPassword,
        "grant_type": "password"
    };

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://192.168.100.35/token',
        withCredentials: true,
        crossdomain: true,
        data: $.param(reqData),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",

        }
    }).then(response => {
        if (this._isMounted) {
            console.log(response.data)
            this.setState({ isToken: true })
            this.setState({ isloggedIn: true })
            this.setState({ authToken: response.data.access_token })
            localStorage.setItem("Token", this.state.authToken)

        }

    })
}
}
```

Comment: how can i call submithandler in componentdidmount sir i am new to react js

Comment: now i am getting this error " Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined "

Comment: You need to pass event in the parenthesis. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: e is not defined where should i defined this e

Comment: issue is still same i have removed e.preventDefault from my submithandler and removed the form tag from jsx problem is still same

Comment: Can you remove SubmitHandler()  method and try calling your API directly inside ComponentDidMount(). Later you can move  the API call in a separate method.

Comment: its working fine if i call it inside componentDidMount but it sending two requests at a time otherwise now the warning is gone but i have to do this on button click sir

Comment: Great! Just wrap your SubmitHandler = (e) => {} in another method and call that method inside ComponentDidMount(). Please mark the answer completed if it helped :)

Comment: u mean i have to create an other method and in that newly created method i have to call my submithandler and then call that new method in componentDidMount method ?

Comment: it is giving this error here Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression `componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
        this.onClickSubmitHandler;

    }`

Comment: i have changed `this.onClickSubmitHandler` to this `this.onClickSubmitHandler()` but still the problem is same